# Strange behaviour of the loss using a custom generator (img,csv)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, loss

I'm working on the RNSA challenge, which consists of predicting the bondage from X-ray scans of kids between 1 and 19 years of age. We're given also the gender for each kid, so I wanted to incorporate it in the model. The image is fed through an InceptionV3, the output is then concatenated (after being max-pooled) with the gender info (which is inserted as an array of all 1s (boys) or all 0s (girls), with dimension chosen by the user).
Therefore the model takes (image,gender) as input. In order to accomplish this I'm using the following generator:

```
def myCustomGen(data_gen = None,dff = None,train = True,batch_size=None,img_size=None,embeddings=32):
      flow = train_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
                                      dataframe=dff,
                                      # directory = 'train-dataset/boneage-training-dataset',
                                      directory = '/content/train-dataset-compress/boneage-training-dataset',
                                      x_col = 'id',
                                      y_col = 'boneage',
                                      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                      shuffle=True,
                                      class_mode='raw',
                                      target_size=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE),
                                      color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                    )

    for x, y in flow:
        indices, filenames = get_indices_from_keras_generator(flow,batch_size)
        genders = reduce(pd.DataFrame.append, map(lambda i: dff[dff.id == i], filenames)).gender_01.values
        genders = create_embeddings2(genders,embedding) #this just creates an array of 0s or 1s with embedding dimension

        if len(x) != len(genders):
          yield [x,genders[-len(y):]],y
        else:
          yield [x,genders],y
```

Where the function get_indices_from_keras_generator() serves the purpose of getting the ids from the unordered batches, which are the used to extract, from each batch, the gender:

```
def get_indices_from_keras_generator(gen, batch_size):
    idx_left = (gen.batch_index - 1) * batch_size
    idx_right = idx_left + gen.batch_size if idx_left >= 0 else None
    indices = gen.index_array[idx_left:idx_right]
    filenames = [gen.filenames[i] for i in indices]
    return indices, filenames
```

Now, here's the thing: the loss is decreasing (both on the training and the validation set) **but** it has a strange pattern: at the start of every epoch, the loss increases a bit, and then after some iterations in the same epoch, it decreases again to end the epoch at a lower value it started with (generally). Here a plot just to point out this saw-tooth behavior:
[loss pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdHYX.png)
**Please note** that the plot above is not the actual loss, is just to make sure the reader grasp the trend of the loss for each epoch.
Why does this happen? Is it expected? If it's unusual, may it be caused by some bad shuffling of the training data? (Although, regarding this last point, the shuffling should be working fine since I use the default keras shuffle in flow_from_dataframe).
Any help is highly appreciated. If you think the generator doesn't work properly you're welcomed in suggesting me a better one.

Comment: I don'T understand the last paragraph, can you post the graph?

Comment: Hello, I added a plot, hopefully it's more clear now! Ps: I had to put a link because stack overflow doesn't allow me yet to post pictures, due to lack of high reputation (I never posted in this site).